# Error during the linking to object file

Tags: c, bash, gcc

I have two simple source files:
main.c

```
void main(){
    print_hello();
}
```

hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_hello(){
    printf("Hellow world \n");
}
```

After compiling with bash command:

```
gcc -c hello.c
gcc -c main.c
```

it's ok. Why when we type `gcc -o hello.o main.o` error is occuring:

```
main.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `print_hello'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but `gcc -o hello hello.o main.o` works fine?

Comment: You should look into what the `-o` flag means.

Comment: do once 'man gcc' search for -o flag .try to understand what does that mean ?

Comment: The `main()` function should have a return type `int`, not `void`. (Even if `main()` lacks a `return` statement, it will implicitly `return 0`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc -o hello.o main.o` means: "Output executable file `hello.o` by linking the subsequent files (`main.o`)".

`gcc -o hello hello.o main.o` means: "Output executable file `hello` by linking the subsequent files (`hello.o` and `main.o`)".

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that you are trying to create a program called `hello.o` from just `main.o`; fortunately, it isn't working.  The argument after the `-o` is the name of the output (program). You need to use something like:

```
gcc -o hello hello.o main.o
```

or

```
gcc -o hello main.o hello.o
```

These specify that the program is to be called `hello` and link both object files.  Alternatively again, you could run:

```
gcc main.o hello.o
```

and this will create a program called `a.out`.

Strictly, you should declare `print_hello()` in `main.c`, preferably via a header file that's used by both source files.  However, that's something of a refinement which you can look to fix after you've created your program.